# JQuery post callback not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post

I saw that there are multiple question on this topic, but I didn't find an answer yet.

JS:

```
$("#signin-form").submit(function(){
   $.post("signin.php", {email: $("#signin_email").val(), password: $("#signin_password").val()}, function(data){
        console.log(data);
   });

});
```

PHP (simplified it since it was not working):

```
<?php
echo "Test";
?>
```

Result: nothing. And an "POST .../signin.php" error in firebug, that dissappears after less than a second which doesn't give me the chance to read it.

I already tried console.log("anything") too.

Comment: I think you form is getting submitted before you see the ajax request.

Comment: That makes sense. How can I fix that? Prevent default?

Comment: Yes or try `return false;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your form seems to be getting submitted, so prevent the default form submission, do:

```
$("#signin-form").submit(function(evt){
   evt.preventDefault();
   $.post("signin.php", {email: $("#signin_email").val(), password: $("#signin_password").val()}, function(data){
        console.log(data);
   });
});
```