# jquery no sending post data

Tags: jquery, post

I am having trouble posting data using jQuery from 1 page to another.  The post is not submitting at all.  I have used Network tab to check the post data and I can see that no form data has been sent.  But I have no idea why.  I tried `evt.preventDefault();` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19581386/1560199). But the result is the same.

So how this works.  index.php posts data to referrer-reason.php which changes the div and runs a new query and displays new data in the div.  #backref is a back button which loads the same code from index.php but in referrer-company.php.  Currently referrer-reason.php isn't posting data to referrer-company.php.  But the same code works when posting data from index.php to referrer-reason.php.

It throws back a 200 OK but no actual content in the post data as you will see below.

I am fairly new to jQuery so this is me trying to keep it simple while I learn it intricately.

Any suggestions on what else I can try?

Code on index.php:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.clickthrough2').click(function () {
    companyId = $(this).attr('id'); 

    $.post('./ajax/referrer-reason.php', {
        clickthrough: $('#company-'+companyId+' .clickthrough').val(),
        ref_date_from2: $('#company-'+companyId+' .ref_date_from2').val(),
        ref_date_to2: $('#company-'+companyId+' .ref_date_to2').val()
    },
    function (data) {
        $('#declined2').html(data);
    });
});     
});
```

POST DATA from index.php to referrer-reason.php.

```
Remote Address:IP:80
Request URL:http://www.domain.com/sections/dash/ajax/referrer-reason.php
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:65
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie:PHPSESSID=****
Host:www.domain.com
Origin:http://www.domain.com
Referer:http://www.domain.com/sections/dash/index.php
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
clickthrough:84
ref_date_from2:1354320000
ref_date_to2:1420934400
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:close
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Sun, 11 Jan 2015 15:46:23 GMT
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.4.33
```

Code on referrer-reason

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#backref').click(function () {
    companyId = $(this).attr('id'); 
    $.post('./ajax/referrer-company.php', {
        clickthrough: $('#company-'+companyId+' .clickthrough').val(),
        ref_date_from2: $('#company-'+companyId+' .ref_date_from2').val(),
        ref_date_to2: $('#company-'+companyId+' .ref_date_to2').val()
    },
    function (data) {
        $('#declined2').html(data);
    });
});     
});
```

POST DATA from referrer-reason.php to referrer-company.php.

```
Remote Address:IP:80
Request URL:http://www.domain.com/sections/dash/ajax/referrer-company.php
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Cookie:PHPSESSID=****
Host:www.domain.com
Origin:http://www.domain.com
Referer:http://www.domain.com/sections/dash/index.php
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:close
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Sun, 11 Jan 2015 15:46:29 GMT
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.4.33
```

**EDIT:** Extra detail requested:

Upon collecting the POST:

```
$selected = $_POST['clickthrough'];
$date_from = $_POST['ref_date_from2'];
$date_to = $_POST['ref_date_to2'];
```

I get:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: clickthrough in /var/www/clients/client1/web51/web/sections/dash/ajax/referrer-company.php on line 35, referer: http://www.domain.com/sections/dash/index.php
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: ref_date_from2 in /var/www/clients/client1/web51/web/sections/dash/ajax/referrer-company.php on line 36, referer: http://www.domain.com/sections/dash/index.php
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: ref_date_to2 in /var/www/clients/client1/web51/web/sections/dash/ajax/referrer-company.php on line 37, referer: http://www.domain.com/sections/dash/index.php
```

Also the 2nd post data has:

```
Content-Length:0
```

The code from referrer-reason.php that is being replaced:

```
            <div id="declined2" class="declined4">
                <h4>Declined Quote <br />Reasons</h4>
                <div class="statgrid">
<?php
    $result = $mysqli->query($quotes_q);    
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
?>
                <div id="company-<?php echo $row['company_id'];?>">
                    <input type="hidden" class="ref_date_from2" value="<?php echo $date_from; ?>" />
                    <input type="hidden" class="ref_date_to2" value="<?php echo $date_to; ?>" />
                    <input type="hidden" class="clickthrough" value="<?php echo $row['company_id'] ?>" />
                        <a><div id="<?php echo $row['company_id'];?>" class="clickthrough2 col-5-6"><?php echo $row['decline_reason']; ?></div></a>
                    <div class="col-1-6"><?php echo $row['company_id_count']; ?></div>  
                </div>
<?php
    }
```

Comment: Can see that the data is sent and status is 200. Explain problem in more detail

Comment: @charlietfl Added extra detail as requested

Comment: Start with 1st one that clearly sends data. What is or isn't happening? Not sure why another page would be mentioned.

Comment: @charlietfl More info added to the top part of the post explaining and the titles of the post data to make it clear.

Comment: So when you send ajax new page is also being loaded? If so defeats purpose of ajax.

Comment: @charlietfl Apologies.  I have added the div that is being replaced.  It is not the whole page just the 1 div.  The style is slightly different from one div to the next.

Comment: Ok and that fills in content properly? Then where does 2nd ajax call come into play? The whole flow process is not very clear

Comment: @charlietfl - There is a back button on referrer-reason.php to take you back to the original list/div, same one that is on index.php.  I have put that div into referrer-company.php so that I can isolate the code as it was not working correctly.

Comment: That means there is a page change somewhere? I am really confused

Comment: @charlietfl Sorry I am probably not helping.  On index.php you have a div with a list of items inside.  When you click on one of the list items it reloads the div from referrer-reason.php with more information relevant to the item selected on the previous div.  The new div has a back button inside of it, which also uses jQuery to reload the same div again, but this time from referral-company.php.  It is however the same date from the first list.  I would have pointed it back to index.php but as it was not working I took it out in order to isolate the code.

Comment: Not sure why it wouldn't send data. WOuld try using `var companyId` to insulate the variable, that can cause isses sometimes and is a really bad practice ignoring `var`. Otherwise do some logging to console and/or set breakpoints to see what's happening within clcik handler. Maybe values aren't being set properly in the response, or ID isn't right ... not sure without direct acces to the DOM

Comment: @charlietfl unfortunately `var` didn't work looking at the console logging now.

Comment: dind't expect that was it, just a bad habit i noticed

Comment: @charlietfl Apologies for wasting your time mate!  Appreciate your help!!  I was incorrectly mapping my divs!  # vs . syndrome lol.  I must be tired!

Comment: happens to all of us . Next time however will have a better grasp on how to build a more understandable question...good luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was incorrectly mapping my divs which is why no logs were coming back.